# How copy what is in char* to char** symbol by symbol in C?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I'm trying to solve this problem and keep getting the same message "Segmentation fault (core dumped)".

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
char* str = "Hello";
char** str1;

int i = 0;
while (*str != '\0')
{
    *(str1[i]) = (str[i]);
    i++;
}
*(str1[i]) = '\0';
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show us what kind of debugging you've done.  I expect you to have run your [mcve] within Valgrind or a similar checker, and to have investigated with a debugger such as GDB, for example.  Ensure you've enabled a full set of compiler warnings, too.  What did the tools tell you, and what information are they missing?  And read Eric Lippert's [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Answer (score 2):

The issue seems to be that your `char**` points to uninitialized memory. If you try to write to that, the code will -most likely- automatically fail. (As it is undefined behavior)

Try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main()
{
    char *str = "Hallo";
    char **str1;
    str1 = malloc(sizeof(char*));
    *str1 = malloc((strlen(str) + 1) * sizeof(char));
    int i = 0;

    while (str[i] != '\0')
    {
        *(*str1 + i) = test[i];
        i++;
    }
    *(*str1 + i) = '\0';
 }
```

Comment: Unfortunately, writing through a wild pointer will *not* automatically fail.  Some debugging problems would be much easier if it did.  But the action does have undefined behavior, and one of the common manifestations is a segfault.

Comment: Agreed, I have edited the answer to hopefully better reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

You have to `malloc` your `char**` before trying to stock data in it.

Comment: Not only does the `char **` need to be initialized with a valid pointer (to allocated space, presumably), but that space also needs to initialized with one or more valid pointers.